# Why using "weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection" in Weka deletes the "@@class@@" attribute

Tags: weka

I am using Weka Explorer in data mining project,
I have too many attributes and I want to reduce them by using Ranking in weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection but when I apply it the Attribute "@@Class@@" is deleted which is must be used in the classifier in next step !

Why attribute  "@@Class@@" is deleted ?
how to solve this problem ?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have not set the `@@Class@@` attribute as the class when performing attribute selection. Ensure you are setting the appropriate class index using `-c` in the command line or `void setClassIndex(int classIndex)` in your Java code.

Comment: Yup it was the solution thank you, but now I have another thing so if you have suggestions again please:
I am working in a Text categorization project using Weka,I have 12 class I need to find text keywords for each class that distinguish one class from others, So I am thinking to make feature vector(FV) for each class independently and store 12 (FV)s in separated 12 arff files!

The Question Is --> How can I combine 12 different Feature vectors in one feature vector?

Comment: I have just answered at the question you have posted regarding this.